# Sofa Upholstery: What's the name of this back cushion technique and how is it done?

Tags: furniture, upholstery

I'm re-upholstering my couch and trying to make synthetic-leather back cushions like this:
[image: sofa made with technique in question]

I'm specifically referring to the horizontal line where the fabric turns-in on itself, creating some "billowing" texture.

What is the name of the technique or method for breaking up the back cushions in this way?  I'd like to know the common name for the technique so I can properly research it.  My couch just has big pillows (no texture) for back cushions now so I can't reverse engineer.

I stumbled upon the term "tufting", and thought it was a variation on that, but all I could find about tufting was for making stuff like this:
[image]
...which is **not** what I want.

How is this done?  Is the front sewed to the back of the cushion, like a "linear tuft"?

I was also thinking one could cut the front fabric of the cushion in an arc, then turn-in the edges of the cut and sew it.

But I'm looking for the industry standard way to get this design.

NOTE: When I find a name for the technique I will update the question title to reflect it.

Comment: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nVyPiPvR2g): How to Make a Pleated Seat Cover for a Motorcycle